Persistent error when accessing an Azure AI Video Indexer API via Logic Apps
I am attempting to use the Create Prompt Content API (with a view to using the Get Prompt Content API) to download some insights from a video I have indexed.
I have created the access token with all the requisite parameters specified in the documentation, and yet I am consistently receiving the following error message:
"ErrorType": "USER_NOT_SIGNED_IN", "Message": "User not found in access token."
I have tried using a manually generated access token, checked my scopes etc.
Nothing is working.
Can anyone help me diagnose this problem please?

Rather than manually creating access token you can create token in the actions itself:
Firstly, get the key from below:

Then place the key below:


Or you can generate here:

Output:

With this you will get correct access token that can be used in next actions.

Hey, thanks for your answer. I should have made clear, I have already done the above. I create an access token as part of my flow, and have confirmed the access token works.

Then it should work, did you checked all the possible ways?

I've checked everything. I really could do with some remote desktop assistance to deal with this. I'm so frustrated.

Also, I'm on an ARM-based account, so I must use the APIs to get the access token, rather than the built-in Logic Apps element you suggested above.

Have you tried running the create prompt content API directly from our API portal? https://api-portal.videoindexer.ai/api-details#api=Operations&operation=Create-Prompt-Content
If that works, what I can suggest is to create a logic app flow with two HTTP actions, first is for retrieving the access token and the second for calling the create prompt content.
First, you will need to configure System Assigned Managed Identity:
Go to the Settings tab and select the Identity blade.
Under the System assigned tab, change the status to "On."
Click "Save" and then "Yes" to confirm.
Click "Azure role assignment" and then "Add role assignment."
Set the scope and permissions for your VI recourse.
Click "Save."
Next, Configure the Video Indexer Get Access Token Connector:
Select "New step" and then choose "HTTP."
Set the name as "Get Access Token."
Use the URL: https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{parameters('subscription_id')}/resourceGroups/@{parameters('account_name')}/providers/Microsoft.VideoIndexer/accounts/Contoso/generateAccessToken?api-version=2024-01-01
Set the method to "POST."
In the body, include:
{
"permissionType": "Contributor",
"scope": "Account"
}
In Advanced parameters, select "Authentication."
Set Authentication Type as "Managed Identity."
Set Managed Identity as "System-assigned managed identity."
Set Audience to https://management.core.windows.net.
Last, create another HTTP action,
this time with
@{parameters('extension_endpoint')}/Accounts/@{parameters('account_id')}/Videos/{videoId}/@{parameters('video_id')}/PromptContent?accessToken=@{body('Parse_JSON')?['accessToken']}

Yes I have, and it works as expected. I have also run the URI string in Postman and some other web-based and local API tools. I just isn't working very specifically in Logic Apps. I have built a new flow in case the current one is bugged, but it still does not work. I am having to try and build a work-around with an Azure Function instead. There is seemingly no explanation for why it constantly fails. Using the Video Indexer Get Access Token Connector doesn't work for me as I have an ARM-based account.
